# List certain installed packages

Tags: command-line, apt, grep

I am trying to see whether I have installed certain packages. I figured this would work

```
apt-get list --installed | grep "xxx"
```

but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
apt list --installed | grep "xxx"
```

Edit: Alternatively, as [Chev_603 wrote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182307/list-certain-installed-packages#comment1975105_1182308), you can do this:

```
dpkg -l | grep "xxx"
```

Edit 2: about `apt list`, see [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html). Looking at [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) shows that `apt-get` does not have the `list --installed` option.

Comment: Or you can do `dpkg -l|grep "xxx"`

Comment: I would recommend to add links or references to man-pages [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) and [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html). They state that `list` is supported by `apt`, not by `apt-get`.

Comment: @Chev_603: `dpkg -l '*xxx*'` is enough.

Comment: [What does "ii" in the first colums of the output of dpkg-query mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459296/what-does-ii-in-the-first-colums-of-the-output-of-dpkg-query-mean)